# Воспроизведение звука с произвольного места

Tags: аудио, c++

Изучаю C++ в VS2008. Проблема следующая.
Чтобы воспроизвести wav-файл, я так понял, надо пользоваться функцией `PlaySound`.
Но звук воспроизводится только с начала. Как еще можно воспроизводить звук и как его можно слушать с произвольного места (например, с 5-ой секунды)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Проигрывание WAV файла из памяти](http://www.firststeps.ru/mfc/mci/r.php?8).

```
MCIDEVICEID mciDeviceID;
mciDeviceID = mciOpenParms.wDeviceID;

MCI_PLAY_PARMS mciPlayParms;
mciPlayParms.dwFrom = 300;
mciPlayParms.dwTo = 600;

mciError = mciSendCommand(mciDeviceID, MCI_PLAY, MCI_FROM | MCI_TO | MCI_WAIT, (DWORD)(LPMCI_PLAY_PARMS)&mciPlayParms);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Похоже разобраться с MCI будет несложно.

Comment: Кстати, спасибо ХэшКоду за вставку примера кода)